# Why length issue in the mentioned string

Tags: go

```
package main  
  
import ("fmt")

func main() {
    lenString: = len("САЛИХА ХАМЗЕЕВНА ГАРИПОВА САЛ ХА ХАМЗЕ ВНА ГАР ПОВА") fmt.Println(lenString)
}
```

Why the length of the string is returning 94 although the length is 51 of the mentioned string

Comment: `len` returns the number of bytes in the string, not the number of characters (runes). Use `utf8.RuneCountInString` to get the number of runes in a string. https://go.dev/play/p/Ecjdsd0bKzf

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation `len` method is counting [number of bytes in string](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#len). Characters in your string are mostly utf-8 encoded. So one character up to 4 bytes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8. So one character is taking more then one byte in your string.

Here is online tool that can prove your results: https://mothereff.in/byte-counter